# AWS Lambda functions Cache. Best way to cache data by 24 hours

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, memcached, amazon-elasticache

I am trying to cache the data (for every user I have in a list) from external URL request using AWS lambda function by almost 24 hours or less.
For instance:

```
cache.set(`response-${user}`, data, 24 * 60 * 60 * 100)
```

I am looking for the best way to save the response, I read that lambda has limited the storage for this.

Also, I read that I can use ElastiCache, but currently I am using [memory-cache](https://www.npmjs.com/package/memory-cache) with node

Thank you,

Comment: Lambda does not cache data. The storage that Lambda uses is not persistent. Sometimes Lambda might run on the same instance and the temporary data is still there but you cannot depend on this. There are other serverless services that can be used for storing data such as DynamoDB. You cannot use Lambda with an in-memory cache for longer than 300 seconds.

Comment: Ok, thank you so much, I have another question, if you know something about alexa... I changed the enpoint in the alexa skill kit, but alexa says "there is a problem comunication with the request skill", and when I see the logs, is comunicating with the old enpoint

Comment: Sorry, I have Alexas all over my house but I have never done any development for them ... yet.

Comment: ok, thank you anyway

Comment: I should have suggested that you create a new question. There are a lot of Alexa developers on Stack Overflow. Make sure that you use the correct tags for your question.